# cloudera vm hadoop Hive fails after fs.http.address ip changed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cloudera

I'm using Cloudera VM (cdh3u2) as a simulated distributed file system. In order to perform file creation and writing from a web server I changed the fs.http.address property to point to the VM IP. This feature works fine.
The problem arises when HIVE perform a map reduce job like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp2;
```

The message I get is:

```
hive> select count(*) from tmp2;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_201111301538_0001, Tracking URL = http://0.0.0.0:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201111301538_0001
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=0.0.0.0:8021 -kill job_201111301538_0001
2011-11-30 16:01:21,773 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2011-11-30 16:01:43,064 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201111301538_0001 with errors
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

Hive executes the following SQL (do not require map reduce job) with no problem:

```
SHOW TABLES;
SELECT * FROM tmp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't respond to IP. change to a dns name